# MAPS V3 ViewPort NAN values

Tags: google-maps-api-3, render, nan

i've recently implemented google  maps integration in a website.

Everything works fine in devel server, but when in production server the map does not render. 
I've tried to create an api key, allowing both the domains in the same key, and nothing changed. Dev works, prod don't.

In firebug I can't see any js errors, just some NAN values in api_viewport call.

Please see the calls below and the js code. Any ideas? Thanks.

DEV server call:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/gen_204?ev=api_viewport&cad=host:MYDEVSERVER,v:14,vr:1,r:1,mt:m,c:39.1685%2C-8.77673,sp:0.01075x0.01687,size:393x323,relsize:0.29,token:99ub4vx1v1,src:apiv3,ts:xz73ff

PROD server call:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/gen_204?ev=api_viewport&cad=host:MYPRODSERVER,v:14,vr:1,r:1,mt:m,c:39.1685%2CNaN,sp:0.01075xNaN,size:393x323,relsize:0.29,token:3c2izptwq8,src:apiv3,ts:xzbbpg

```
$.fn.initPetrolMap = function(){
        $this  = $(this);
        var s  = document.createElement('script');
        s.type = "text/javascript";
        s.src  = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY&sensor=true&callback=loadPetrolMap";

        window.loadPetrolMap = function(){
            // console.log($this.data('map'));
            var lt = $this.data('map').lat;
            var ln = $this.data('map').lng; 
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 15,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(lt,ln),
                mapTypeControl: true,
                navigationControl: true,
                navigationControlOptions: {
                    style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
                },

                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById($this.prop('id')),
                                mapOptions);

            var image = $this.data('map').marker;
            var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lt, ln);
            var stationMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatLng,
                map: map,
                icon: image
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(stationMarker, 'click', function() {
                var url = 'https://maps.google.com/maps?daddr='+lt+','+ln+'&hl=en&sll='+lt+','+ln+'&t=m&mra=mift&mrsp=2&sz=5&z=15';
                window.open(url);

            });

        };

        $("head").append(s);  
     };
```

Comment: Where do `$this.data('map').lat` & `$this.data('map').lng` come from?  Looks to me like `$this.data('map').lng` is missing from your non-working map.

Comment: Actually, those parameters come from a html5 data property. But your comment made me look again there, and i found the problem. Just a wrong parameter reference.

Comment: So the problem was in the call/configuration and not in the information provided in your question?

Comment: I had to change a variable name because of a google closurejs compression error, and i forgot to change it in the markup in the production environment. Once i've synched the files everything worked fine.